# Workbox's precache manifest file contains invalid URL strings in Laravel Mix setting

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm using **Workbox 3.0** (webpack-plugin) and **Laravel Mix** (5.6) to auto-generate a ServiceWorker file.

When running the webpack compiler, the manifest file generated by Workbox for pre-cached assets looks like this:

```
self.__precacheManifest = [
  {
    "revision": "89c25ce71806a695a25e",
    "url": "//js/app.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "89c25ce71806a695a25e",
    "url": "//css/app.css"
  }
];
```

Obviously, the URL strings are wrong and cause errors on the actual web page.

Here is my *webpack.mix.js*: (relevant parts)

```
const {InjectManifest} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin')
mix.webpackConfig({
  plugins: [
    new InjectManifest({
      swSrc: './resources/assets/js/sw.js'
    })
  ]
})
```

While *InjectManifest* is used here to have precaching as well as my own dynamic caching, the same happens when using the *GenerateSW* plugin instead.

and my source *sw.js*:

```
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest || [])
```

Any idea how to solve this? If I manually modify the *precacheManifest*, it works fine:

```
self.__precacheManifest = [
  {
    "revision": "89c25ce71806a695a25e",
    "url": "./js/app.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "89c25ce71806a695a25e",
    "url": "./css/app.css"
  }
];
```

**Steps to reproduce this:**

1. Create a new Laravel Project: `Laravel new <proj_name>`
2. `cd <proj_name>`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm install --save-dev workbox-webpack-plugin`
5. Add these lines to webpack.mix.js to configure it for Workbox:

> const { GenerateSW } = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
>
> mix.webpackConfig({ plugins: [new GenerateSW()] });

6. run `php artisan make:auth` and `php artisan migrate` to complete the frontend scaffolding
7. Edit bootstrap.js in the \resources\assets\js folder to include the usual code to register the new ServiceWorker
8. run `npm run dev`

The compiled precache-manifest file looks like this:

```
self.__precacheManifest = [
  {
    "revision": "b922e094256b9404e705",
    "url": "//js/app.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "b922e094256b9404e705",
    "url": "//css/app.css"
  }
];
```

Comment: I tried adding e.g. 

    _importsDirectory: './public'_

to the webpackConfig object but to no avail.

Comment: What is your `output.publicPath` value in your webpack config?

Comment: I'm actually not modifying the webpack.config.js file directly - this is all handled by Laravel Mix. But looking at the webpack.config.js file in the node_modules directory (node_modules/laravel-mix/setup), the publicPath is not defined there either.

Comment: The code that generates those URLs is https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/v3.0.0/packages/workbox-webpack-plugin/src/lib/get-manifest-entries-from-compilation.js#L189 It effectively concatenates `publicPath` and the implicit URL that webpack creates for an asset. Can you provide a link to your full project that we could clone and try locally to reproduce?

Comment: I have added steps to reproduce the problem from scratch using a standard Laravel installation with Workbox

Comment: Project to demonstrate this problem: https://github.com/matthiku/laravelAndWorkbox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution:

As Laravel is using the "Laravel Mix" API to configure and run WebPack, the way to configure WebPack is to modify the file `webpack.mix.js`.

Jeff Posnick pointed me into the right direction. If I add the following lines into `webpack.mix.js`, the compiler produces a correct precache manifest file -

```
const { GenerateSW } = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
mix.webpackConfig({
  plugins: [new GenerateSW()],
  output: {
    publicPath: ''
  }
});
```

The solution is to provide simply an empty string for the *output.publicPath* configuration option of webpack.

However, if you need to provide an actual path for the publicPath option, this workaround will fail. See bug report here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1534

Comment: This works fine unless I load a page with a path. For example on my page `/goals/add/` it tries to load `/goals/js/44.94b7a16456b6a9589b3f.js` which obviously doesn't exist. Any ideas?