# How to change precache paths for WorkboxPlugin? (Using Jigsaw Php-Framework)

Tags: workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

My problem is that the paths are not set correctly. For example in service-worker.js it creates:

```
importScripts(
  "/precache-manifest.5f7aa7298db0e8d002e09a10e9d6d1b1.js"
);
```

but since I'm using Jigsaw Framework and the public location is different it must be

```
importScripts(
  "/assets/build/precache-manifest.5f7aa7298db0e8d002e09a10e9d6d1b1.js"
);
```

The same is for the precache-file itself, all the paths are wrong:

```
self.__precacheManifest = (self.__precacheManifest || []).concat([
  {
    "revision": "43301cc5590faa3a374f",
    "url": "//js/main.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "43301cc5590faa3a374f",
    "url": "/css/main.css"
  },
```

Must be

```
self.__precacheManifest = (self.__precacheManifest || []).concat([
  {
    "revision": "43301cc5590faa3a374f",
    "url": "/assets/build/js/main.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "43301cc5590faa3a374f",
    "url": "/assets/build/css/main.css"
  },
```

I tried to play with the globDirectory setting, but it didn't work.

Here is my "standard" Webpack config:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
const build = require('./tasks/build.js');


mix.disableSuccessNotifications();
mix.setPublicPath('source/assets/build');
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        build.jigsaw,
        build.browserSync(),
        build.watch(['source/**/*.md', 'source/**/*.php', 'source/**/*.scss', '!source/**/_tmp/*']),
        new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
            // these options encourage the ServiceWorkers to get in there fast
            // and not allow any straggling "old" SWs to hang around
            clientsClaim: true,
            skipWaiting: true,
        }),
    ],
});

mix.js('source/_assets/js/main.js', 'js')
    .sass('source/_assets/sass/main.scss', 'css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [tailwindcss()],
    })
    .version();
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of this: [Workbox's precache manifest file contains invalid URL strings in Laravel Mix setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760754/workboxs-precache-manifest-file-contains-invalid-url-strings-in-laravel-mix-set?rq=1)

I found out that I can set my path like this:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        build.jigsaw,
        build.browserSync(),
        build.watch(['source/**/*.md', 'source/**/*.php', 'source/**/*.scss', '!source/**/_tmp/*']),
        new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
            // these options encourage the ServiceWorkers to get in there fast
            // and not allow any straggling "old" SWs to hang around
            clientsClaim: true,
            skipWaiting: true,
        }),
    ],
    output: {
        publicPath: '/assets/build/', // fixes the output bug
    },
});
```

I'm not sure, but in the other question, they say that it will fail when a specific path is set. Until now everything looks fine and my Service Worker works fine :)