# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch - Service worker with workbox

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to setup my service worker using Workbox through the Workbox Webpack plugin, however.
Below is my Workbox config

```
module.exports = {
    swDest: "./service-worker.js",
    swSrc: "./resources/js/service-worker.js",
    precacheManifestFilename: './js/wb-manifest.[manifestHash].js',
    importWorkboxFrom: 'disabled',
};
```

Below is the service worker that gets generated

```js
importScripts("/js/wb-manifest.52d5032189ed9e06abfcddfea1d2c06f.js");

importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

if (workbox) {
    workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest)
    // top-level routes we want to precache
    workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(['/']);

    // injected assets by Workbox CLI
    workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);

    // match routes for homepage, blog and any sub-pages of blog
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
        /^\/(?:(home)?(\/.*)?)$/,
        new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
            cacheName: 'static-resources',
        })
    );

    // js/css files
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
        /\.(?:js|css)$/,
        new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
            cacheName: 'static-resources',
        })
    );

    // images
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
        // Cache image files.
        /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
        // Use the cache if it's available.
        new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
            // Use a custom cache name.
            cacheName: 'image-cache',
            plugins: [
                new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
                    // Cache upto 50 images.
                    maxEntries: 50,
                    // Cache for a maximum of a week.
                    maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
                })
            ],
        })
    );
}
```

and this is the `/js/wb-manifest.52d5032189ed9e06abfcddfea1d2c06f.js` file content

```js
self.__precacheManifest = (self.__precacheManifest || []).concat([
  {
    "revision": "58db2a6d21fa1a19dd78",
    "url": "//js/app.css"
  },
  {
    "revision": "58db2a6d21fa1a19dd78",
    "url": "//js/app.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "1ca2e7253612557def06",
    "url": "//js/manifest.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "c2e3808fc82a0df6550a",
    "url": "//js/vendor.js"
  },
  {
    "url": "/fonts/vendor/slick-carousel/slick/slick.eot?ced611daf7709cc778da928fec876475"
  },
  {
    "url": "/fonts/vendor/slick-carousel/slick/slick.svg?f97e3bbf73254b0112091d0192f17aec"
  },
  {
    "url": "/fonts/vendor/slick-carousel/slick/slick.ttf?d41f55a78e6f49a5512878df1737e58a"
  },
  {
    "url": "/fonts/vendor/slick-carousel/slick/slick.woff?b7c9e1e479de3b53f1e4e30ebac2403a"
  },
  {
    "url": "/fonts/vendor/video.js/dist/VideoJS.eot?46ac6629168546c71dbf115992aa4be9"
  },
  {
    "url": "/fonts/vendor/vue-goodshare/src/fontello.eot?a1386b4bdc2b24439baa8bdd5d89959c"
  },
  {
    "url": "/fonts/vendor/vue-goodshare/src/fontello.svg?2382f1e627c684dc977d16df37313927"
  },
  {
    "url": "/fonts/vendor/vue-goodshare/src/fontello.ttf?6eb82fdf9c4acf6f47221c82f77bacda"
  },
  {
    "url": "/fonts/vendor/vue-goodshare/src/fontello.woff2?24fc0a90fb74e9ac5ef0ec2df3c5deff"
  },
  {
    "url": "/fonts/vendor/vue-goodshare/src/fontello.woff?a51fe381a51e7d8672467515ea21c366"
  },
  {
    "revision": "3b4287d70ff9b954bd4e61dc5d84859f",
    "url": "/images/Profile.png"
  },
  {
    "revision": "81253a830a11114a1193273cf3abff66",
    "url": "/images/X-submit.png"
  },
  {
    "revision": "6638168869f2fe8039a76f1bf0e8bb93",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/Thumbs.db"
  },
  {
    "revision": "70f78829e74e0585890bc32a5d02a1a2",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/academic_award.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "a527ccce987d174048b41b3ee224f842",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/accelerator_program.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "ea6a415e0bfa0396299d5878b9bedc90",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/audience_management.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "498dcb007045a8e51f19098930b9627d",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/communiry_award.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "85546813c0409eda399a7992866168eb",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/educational_institution.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "14bf9f25b8c478f9a37eba77f57d1c7b",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/employee_onboarding.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "b9398f6d8856c369a7573225849e6f4c",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/employee_survey.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "e83d193c3e187d23439ef3d1eee4bd28",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/enterprise_asset_management.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "4f0b52794f3a7ecdfd817a828e225f80",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/enterprise_offices.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "4348ede5b2a4cd567dab3463661f888f",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/fellowship_application.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "26492ef3f153ce7de198019e706f3729",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/field_service.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "62c7daf76295d8b77e532f37ab216db8",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/film_casting.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "69771eec9bff771c5a8b5942fe5e1b58",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/fleet_management.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "6190d4d10b375c9f13a6466ea3108a33",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/giveaway.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "b8bb319e8733f9ca92f1fadb683fa002",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/graduate_program.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "d3e45b131750b28898bb09f2f6b59fa4",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/incubator_program.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "a42ffe7c6ecaac09d3a127af6a430c0c",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/industry_assessment.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "0a6950dfe04b1f93e858c2351fd51e37",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/internal_award.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "131fbfa7fe4c69cd4696ff3a581cf1fc",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/internship.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "e4be69cf3cea9bddecc8812907b5b8ec",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/interview_survey.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "4711648d28dd44ab7e07ca7ec277e3fa",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/job_application.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "8b3ed79c6d245d44bd12a1315d5861bb",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/marketing_competition.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "e51b9c71763fd9b15259fa9d2eb41f9e",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/non_profit.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "fde76d940c2f65c52e1b6d9c23e35994",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/online_judging.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "64a2c807e007ce227cfff8bdd592bb4e",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/online_voting.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "cfb7e1f57d969588ebda9ced13934a4a",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/performance_assessment.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "8c3a28272780452e77d179441a4e1137",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/professional_award.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "642f301006b2d0d929f54c960228009d",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/program_admission.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "4a4df433096b6524b067c8934cb15243",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/request_form.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "edb64d6ea40f38d81af1eb5db9779ff1",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/safety_management.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "674f5c9a0128f28088a5e84d1e344070",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/scholarship.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "218bea423d09f570d5cb1d8b0558d078",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/staff_recruitment.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "2eb163f910ce3937e67e0c0a5298b668",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/stage_casting.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "46eba3ea3605402c935ba607f0947966",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/state_local_Government.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "358284bec168fe38332e941b0af6ce65",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/student_grant.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "60dfc0cc3b9fb7346ada6de55c2ccc1a",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/student_portfolio_assessment.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "9124eabd633c811de6f5fb99d03157b0",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/student_societies_management.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "c7b9eabaa0059dc941c157e5a181b1af",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/sweepstakes_contest.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "f27300ce7f32fcccdc4eb1051bc66f76",
    "url": "/images/campaign_categories/tv_casting.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "e835944d6dfc35226c85fd0a012a3eb4",
    "url": "/images/campaign_type/academic_submission.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "1c40689c95f4c50bc2b6e70dc8429382",
    "url": "/images/campaign_type/awards_competition.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "f02d96942f8e430359c10b25a53afb0a",
    "url": "/images/campaign_type/field_operation.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "ae4ed74a388c958ce2c6f75973cafc3c",
    "url": "/images/campaign_type/grant_management.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "80e723058ef019e93fe0b9815e9abf2c",
    "url": "/images/campaign_type/human_resource.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "be43ad2a1752a4fbc1c47d35986510dd",
    "url": "/images/campaign_type/tv_creative.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "66d80bb66ecba51224238a2fa61255bf",
    "url": "/images/cover1.png"
  },
  {
    "revision": "24ae6c3603ab12525f784c4695e4a16c",
    "url": "/images/default-campaign-background.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "d3e45b131750b28898bb09f2f6b59fa4",
    "url": "/images/demo.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "8672feca6084ae8308865a8d76315e82",
    "url": "/images/home/cta-bg.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "5bb108ad99b46930234e97aeba1d9c36",
    "url": "/images/icons/icon-128x128.png"
  },
  {
    "revision": "bcac35bc022ff204a158d9f64571270c",
    "url": "/images/icons/icon-144x144.png"
  },
  {
    "revision": "261c29dbca3b4c95be5b086d80e0342f",
    "url": "/images/icons/icon-152x152.png"
  },
  {
    "revision": "acd7199353f0c533a370b8d1a26f65ad",
    "url": "/images/icons/icon-192x192.png"
  },
  {
    "revision": "eb58a472c79a7b0b69f61fe7344225a9",
    "url": "/images/icons/icon-384x384.png"
  },
  {
    "revision": "dec89a9ff463802f64fb73af44e4c8af",
    "url": "/images/icons/icon-512x512.png"
  },
  {
    "revision": "8d42388484564d51d353e98081e8396d",
    "url": "/images/icons/icon-72x72.png"
  },
  {
    "revision": "38c3663048c00896726df78ceb7b625a",
    "url": "/images/icons/icon-96x96.png"
  },
  {
    "revision": "1e313bcd7806d462e191eb9e71c19c9f",
    "url": "/images/login-bg.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "f2bad45ccfcca1304bb999d54cd1bf6a",
    "url": "/images/unite-the-process.jpg"
  },
  {
    "revision": "9c74e172f87984c48ddf5c8108cabe67",
    "url": "/images/vendor/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/flags.png"
  },
  {
    "revision": "b98efd98a75fae94e66cfabbcf36805b",
    "url": "/images/vendor/slick-carousel/slick/ajax-loader.gif"
  },
  {
    "url": "/images/vendor/slick-carousel/slick/ajax-loader.gif?c5cd7f5300576ab4c88202b42f6ded62"
  },
  {
    "revision": "2b169e261fc22822832d",
    "url": "/js/modules/@tinymce/tinymce-vue.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "895bfdf4b4154838fa11",
    "url": "/js/modules/campaign.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "c86b9cd91933c568b99d",
    "url": "/js/modules/form.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "8bb3bf98b7f6a4f03797",
    "url": "/js/modules/form/builder.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "cd36d2f87ad49edd8589",
    "url": "/js/modules/form~js/modules/form/builder~js/modules/questionnaire/form/renderer.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "e0cbb01807951268e840",
    "url": "/js/modules/front/catalog.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "765d276342e109fe38a4",
    "url": "/js/modules/front/error.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "55da0251ad210b041e07",
    "url": "/js/modules/front/front.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "835e705dfd112a7dad37",
    "url": "/js/modules/front/front~js/modules/front/home.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "b7a3c5e7870c10b42904",
    "url": "/js/modules/front/home.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "2b89029a7ffef28bbb76",
    "url": "/js/modules/front/voting.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "2d1761ca7e1c85ba15f0",
    "url": "/js/modules/manage.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "b4ccb8c2aa4c67dd70f2",
    "url": "/js/modules/notification.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "5c557a2f5e0e7177d0ad",
    "url": "/js/modules/questionnaire/form/renderer.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "991cef8ce7809f331140",
    "url": "/js/modules/submissions.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "748f31e36ce18beabddd",
    "url": "/js/modules/video.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "25218ac3c90251593c8a",
    "url": "/js/modules/xlsx.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "1991ff4315fd7941818f",
    "url": "/vendors~js/modules/campaign.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "63a3dce539dec0c540fb",
    "url": "/vendors~js/modules/campaign~js/modules/front/voting~js/modules/manage.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "b687cafabd74f6c4f4a0",
    "url": "/vendors~js/modules/campaign~js/modules/front/voting~js/modules/questionnaire/form/renderer.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "1e657d82ab6a93806d98",
    "url": "/vendors~js/modules/dropzone.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "5e6a833bb6847d739758",
    "url": "/vendors~js/modules/form/builder~js/modules/questionnaire/form/renderer.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "b008f08ed09e95f00626",
    "url": "/vendors~js/modules/front/front.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "55727bf869f30b23442b",
    "url": "/vendors~js/modules/front/voting.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "8bf2f1f289dcf20cd599",
    "url": "/vendors~js/modules/gantt-elastic.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "2699b2cd12d6cbcd2234",
    "url": "/vendors~js/modules/video.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "f1a926bb27f045c343f6",
    "url": "/vendors~js/modules/xlsx.js"
  }
]);
```

However when I register the service worker and run the page I get the error

> service-worker.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

I have tried a couple of things to see what might be causing it, and it seems to be an issue with the importScripts at the top of the service worker.

I'd like to know if there is anything wrong with my service worker and how to get it fixed.

Comment: I tried something similar to this using laravel-mix and can confirm the same error. Have u solved this error?

Comment: No @Aniket I have not been able to solve this problem

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem and fixed it by simply disabling the ad blocker browser extension. In some cases this may be helpful.

Comment: Having the same issue. Is there a way to get around this with ad blockers? I tried a try catch, but it still threw an error.

Comment: thanks man! Disabling the AD Blocker saved my day :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you already fixed the problem? I was experiencing the exact same issue in laravel mix. Please check out your precaching file. Does it look like this:

```
self.__precacheManifest = [
{
    "revision": "89c25ce71806a695a25e",
    "url": "//js/app.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "89c25ce71806a695a25e",
    "url": "//css/app.css"
  }
];
```

If so, please check out this fix:
[Workbox's precache manifest file contains invalid URL strings in Laravel Mix setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760754/workboxs-precache-manifest-file-contains-invalid-url-strings-in-laravel-mix-set)

Add the publicPath option to your webpack config

```
const { GenerateSW } = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');

mix.webpackConfig({
  plugins: [new GenerateSW()],
  output: {
    publicPath: ''
  }
});
```

That fixed the issue for me! Hope it helpes you too

Answer (score 2):

I face the same issue, solved it after reading this https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/689#issuecomment-316470843

In my case, use `publicPath:''`  will cause some router redirect issue.
I use the `modifyURLPrefix`

```
modifyURLPrefix: {
    '//': '/'
},
```

Comment: thanks. you save my time. I add this to laravel-mix-workbox additional configuration and it work. when I set publicPath to '' its case problem with js chunk files routing