# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch Nextjs PWA using next-pwa in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, next.js, progressive-web-apps, next-pwa

Hi  I was working on a Nextjs proyect and i try to convert it to a PWA using next-pwa, first i created the next.config.js

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa');

module.exports = withPWA({
    pwa: {
        dest: 'public',
      }
});
```

then created the manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "PRONTO APP",
  "short_name": "PRONTO",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/icon.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "theme_color": "#FFFFFF",
  "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

And I add the meta data in de _document file in pages

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <Html>
                <Head>
                    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icon.png" />
                    <meta name='theme-color' content="#fff" />
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    };
}

export default MyDocument;
```

But when i run:

```
npm build dev 
npm start
```

in Google Chrome My PWA works fine but in console i get this error:
in other browsers this error doesn't appear

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch`

And I really dont know why, running the app in dev mod with npm run dev i get the following messages in chrome:

```
workbox Router is responding to: /
workbox Network request for '/' threw an error. TypeError: Failed to fetch
workbox Using NetworkOnly to respond to '/'
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

This is my public folder structure:

```
/public
-/fonts
-/images
-favicon.ico
-icon-512x512.png}
-icon.png
-manifest.json
-sw.js
```

I was trying to do the same thing in this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8enp-acPbRE

Can Anyone Help me plss

Comment: coult it be related to some extensions like adblock enabled like in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257586/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-service-worker-with-workbox

Comment: I like the adblock suggestion. Have you tried to stop on exceptions using the chrome devtools?

Comment: I have 0 extensions in the browser, and i disable the default chrome add block  for testing and that error still show in console :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same error using Chrome `89` and Workbox `6.1.1`. 
After updating Chrome to `90` (and Workbox to `6.1.5`), this error is gone.

See related thread: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2749